# From where can I get the design docs of the android email application?

Tags: android, email

Now I want to read the android email application in http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/packages/apps/Email/, but I find I lack of fundamental basis to digest this complex code. So I want some design docs as a guide, such as high level design and low level design or any other overview docs. I engage in email application developing for the first time.

Comment: High level design, low level design....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want some design docs as a guide, such as high level design and low level design or any other overview docs.

Generally speaking, there are few design documents for the AOSP available publicly. And since the email app lacks a `docs/` directory (AFAICT), it is safe to assume that no such documents are available for that app.

You may be better served working with the K-9 project, which forked from the AOSP email application a few years ago, and may have more published design documentation.